# Why is the kernel - $(1-|\gamma_i-\gamma_j|) \ k_{SE}$ - non-stationary?

Tags: regression, gaussian-process, stationarity, kernel-smoothing

> Stationary kernel which only depends upon the lag between the inputs and not on the absolute values of the inputs.

Having read this guideline, I was wondering why the following kernel mentioned in [1] (which deals with Gaussian process regression) is non-stationary.

\begin{equation}
k(\mathbf{x}_i,\mathbf{x}_j)=(1-|\gamma_i-\gamma_j|) \ k_{SE}(\mathbf{x}_i,\mathbf{x}_j), 
\end{equation}

where $k_{SE}$ is a standard squared exponential kernel and $\gamma_i,\gamma_j$ are parameters depending upon the $i^{th}$ and $j^{th}$ inputs. A standard squared exponential kernel is given by:

$\hspace{90pt} k_{SE}(\mathbf{x}_i,\mathbf{x}_j)=\sigma_f^2\ exp(-\frac{1}{2} \ \frac{||{\mathbf{x}_i-\mathbf{x}_j||}^2}{\sigma_l^2})$,

where $\{\sigma_f^2,\sigma_l^2\}$ are hyperparameters.

**My question is**: How is $k(\mathbf{x}_i,\mathbf{x}_j)$ a non-stationary kernel, if it depends upon $||\mathbf{x}_i-\mathbf{x}_j||$ and $|\gamma_i-\gamma_j|$ (basically only lag between the inputs).

**Another question is**: If I define $\gamma_i = c \ \forall \ i$, where $c=\{-1,0,1\}$ but the chosen value for $c$ depends on the $i^{th}$ input, would the kernel still be non-stationary?

[1] Choi, Sungjoon, et al. "Leveraged Non-Stationary Gaussian Process Regression for Autonomous Robot Navigation.", in ICRA 2015.

Comment: This question seems to contain its own answer: if indeed "$\gamma_i$ and $\gamma_j$ are parameters depending on" something related to $i$ and $j$, then that's *prima facie* evidence of non-stationarity.  (I'm not sure what exactly you mean by "inputs", though.)

Comment: @whuber: is this really true? I thought that kernel stationarity means that the kernel is invariant under translations in space, and the only space dependent parameters here are $\mathbf{x}_i$, with $\|\mathbf{x}_i-\mathbf{x}_j\|$ being stationary. The $\gamma_i$ don't change under translations. So it looks like the kernel is indeed stationary.

Comment: @Alex Is what "really true"? I still have little idea what the $\gamma_i$ and $\gamma_j$ are. It looks possible--even likely--that they *do* change under translations, depending on what the term "$i^\text{th}$ input" might mean.

Comment: @whuber: I see what you mean, I interpreted it as $\gamma_i$ depending only on index $i$.

Comment: @whuber I understood it after giving it some more thought. $\gamma_i$ can be written as $f_(x_i)$ and so it is no longer a function of $||\mathbf{x}_i-\mathbf{x}_j||$ only. Thank you.